# PHP Collection flatten object only if it contains a key

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I want to flatten some items in an array if they contain a key of `items` so for example the following object:

```json
{
  "key1": {
    "order": 1,
    "name": "Test"
  },
  "group1": {
    "order": 1,
    "name": "Test",
    "items": {
      "key2": {
        "order": 1,
        "name": "Test"
      },
      "key3": {
        "order": 1,
        "name": "Test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Should be flattened to be formatted like follows, so basically removing the items within the group to the root level:

```json
{
  "key1": {
    "order": 1,
    "name": "Test"
  },
  "key2": {
    "order": 1,
    "name": "Test"
  },
  "key3": {
    "order": 1,
    "name": "Test"
  }
}
```

I have put this object into a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` so I can use `flatMap`. `flatten` doesn't work, as I don't want to completely flatten it.

Comment: Can you share a `var_export()` of your input array?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Laravel, did you take a resource and collection in consideration? You could also try the Laravel `collapse()` method which can be found here: [collapse method on collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-collapse)

```
$collection = collect([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
]);

$collapsed = $collection->collapse();

$collapsed->all();

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Not full on Laravel, we are using some of the packages. Just double check the question again mate, I can't full on collapse, maybe collapse/flatten was the wrong word.